# FireFox is very slow in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

When ever i try to automate my application in firefox its taking so much time to load and finally showing "The Connection had Timed Out",and the same app  is working perfectly in IE and Chrome.Is there any way to speed up the FireFox? or any browser level settings to be done?.Im using webDriver 2.37,FF 25.0
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ajay Talpur

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) CHANGELOG. Webdriver latest version supports only till Firefox 24. Downgrade your firefox version and you will not see this issue.

Comment: Thank you i will try downgrading my FF & re-execute my script again

Comment: I also have glacially slow Selenium tests. Downgrading to Firefox 24 did not help. (Running on Ubuntu via vagrant/VirtualBox, displayed on Windows 7 via Cygwin X11 server.)

Answer (score 0):

Check Proxy settings, as Chrome used IE proxy settings application might have working correct over there. You have to set proxy for Firefox it will not pick it up from IE.